# Pandas : substract the same number in each row of a Serie

Tags: python, pandas, series

I'm trying to make a merge between two Dataframes. For that, I used the read_csv() function of pandas.

There is one Serie (full of integers) in common between the two DF. But here's the values of the first file's Serie :

```
df1['id']

0       87784769
1       87784819
2       87784850
3       87784744
4       87784884
5       87721464
6       87721332
7       87721225
```

And here's the seconde one :

```
df2['id']

0       784769
1       784819
2       784850
3       784744
4       784884
5       721464
6       721332
7       721225
```

Values are not the same because in the first one each number has 87000000 apart. Consequently, the merge function can"t work !

(precision : I used the same index for the post, but it's different between my two df)

I thought substract 87000000 from each row of df1['id'], but I didn't found the right function in pandas...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `df1['id'] - 87000000` ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
df1['id'] -= 87000000
```

what is same as:

```
df1['id'] = df1['id'] - 87000000
```

If `merge` function does not work check if same dtypes in both `id` in both `df`.

```
print (df1['id'].dtype)
print (df2['id'].dtype)
```

If not, convert them both to `int`:

```
df2['id'] = df2['id'].astype(int)
```

Comment: Very cool, I tried that and thought there was an error because of a message in the notebook. Thank you :-) !